# Incompatible types when using lower bound wildcard

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I can't understand why I have a compilation error for this code:

```
private static <T> Consumer<T> f3()
{
    return t -> {};
}

private static <T> Consumer<? super T> f4()
{
    return t -> {};
}


@Test
public void test()
{
    Consumer<Integer> action3 = f3();
    Consumer<Integer> action4 = f4(); // ERROR
}
```

the error from javac 1.8.0_161:

> Error:(84, 36) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) `T` exist so that `java.util.function.Consumer<? super T>` conforms to `java.util.function.Consumer<java.lang.Void>`

Can anyone explain this error? Thanks.

**EDIT**
I tried to simplify my example, and I did an error by making it too simple. What I'm interested is an explanation for this error which is output by IntelliJ:

```
private static <T> BiConsumer<T, ? super Throwable> f1(Consumer<? super Throwable> consumer)
{
    return null;
}

private static <T> BiConsumer<? super T, ? super Throwable> f2(Consumer<? super Throwable> consumer)
{
    return null;
}

@Test
public void test()
{
    BiConsumer<? super Integer, ? super Throwable> action1 = f1(throwable -> { });
    BiConsumer<? super Integer, ? super Throwable> action2 = f2(throwable -> { });  // ERROR HERE
}
```

IntelliJ considers this an error because "inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: T lower bounds: Integer".
But when compiling it, it's fine, no error. Is this an actually valid Java code and just a bug in IntelliJ? Thanks.

Comment: @AndyTurner I've edited to indicate where the error is, sorry for that.

Answer (score 5):

A `Consumer<? super Something>` isn't a `Consumer<Integer>`.

The compiler doesn't know that there are no producer methods on the `Consumer` class, so it stops you potentially using it as a producer.

As far as the type inference rules are concerned, there is no difference between `Consumer` and `List`, for example. So the same rule which stops you writing the following also stops you in what you are doing:

```
List<? super Integer> c = Arrays.asList("");
List<Integer> d = c;        // Compiler error; let's pretend it works.
Integer i = d.get(0);       // ClassCastException!
```

Answer (score 1):

An answer for your edit:

I suspect this is a bug in intellij. If I remove the variable declaration, and then select the expression and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to extract a variable, it picks the following type:

```
BiConsumer<? super Object, ? super Throwable> biConsumer = f2(throwable -> {});
```

which, despite just having picked itself, it highlights the lambda as an error.

Comment: I also think it's a bug: if I change the return type of f2 from BiConsumer to Consumer, it works. Thanks.

Comment: @FlorinM JetBrains do seem pretty snappy at fixing bugs!

Answer (score 0):

Please try File->Invalidate Caches and restart.